# Renaming or setting object names dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, constructor, naming

I'm fairly new to JavaScript I setup below to use keys and values for different items I need to work. All the values will be the same using a variable to distinguish each item (which will just be it, but I would like to identify each item (itemObject) which I'm also using for the variable name.

Abbreviated example::

```
function objFunction (itemName) {
    itemObject = {
        object1Data: [{
            data1: {
                prop1: 'value',
                prop2: 'value'
            },
            data2: {
                prop1: itemName + 'some string'
                prop2: itemNamevariable
            }
        }],
        object2: {
            data: {
                prop1: itemName,
                prop2:  itemName + 'some string'
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Or am I better off using a constructor or another method?

```
function ObjFunction (itemName) {
    this.itemObject = {
        bject1Data: [{
            data1: {
                prop1: 'value',
                prop2: 'value'
            },
            data2: {
                prop1: itemName + 'some string',
                prop2: itemName
            }
        }],
        object2: {
            data: {
                prop1:  itemName,
                prop2:  itemName + 'some string'
            }
        }
     }
}

var item1 = new ObjFunction('item1Name');
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to somehow link those properties with the variable such that when the variable changes, those properties change automatically? Or....?

Comment: Your first example works (provided `itemNamevariable` is meant to be `itemName`), but A) Falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), and 2) Doesn't *return* `itemObject`. (Your second example also works, but you don't need a constructor just to create an object.)

Comment: Yes, I'm linking those with a variable determined by a user selection(s) at runtime. I know I can add 'use strict', but we still have customers on IE8/9. I'm not 100% sure if that would cause problems. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I would have to create an object for every item if I didn't use a constructor correct?

Comment: You can't link a property to a variable passed into a function as an argument anyway, there are not one but two places where all link to the variable has been lost, as JavaScript is purely pass-by-value. So when you call the function, the *value* of the variable (not a reference to the variable) is passed. Then when you assign that to a property, the *value* gets assigned, not a link to the argument or variable it came from. Strict mode has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first answer, just change the second line from:

```
itemObject = {
```

to

```
return {
```

and then you can say:

```
var item1 = objFunction('item1Name');
```

In other words:

```
function objFunction (itemName) {
    return {'name' : itemName};
}

var y = objFunction("theName");
console.log(y.name);
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfect. I don't necessarily need the second option. Now i can use these objects much more easily and simplify the code.